# Ubuntu Upgrade 21.10

Tags: upgrade, 21.10

I just upgraded to 21.10 (from 20.04) now every time I install any new program (whether trough the CLI command or the Ubuntu Software) it installs OK; but when I try to run them it seems to start but it never fully runs; fading into oblivion. Any known issues with 21.10? Have "sudo lshw" output!

Comment: It's about to become end of life.

Comment: Providing specifics may help us to understand, ie. what application(s), if run from terminal do you get any warnings/errors before it ends?  Have you explored `/var/crash/` for any helpful details?   The notice of 21.10's coming EOL is now out - https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2022-May/000280.html so be aware you'll need to *release-upgrade* to 22.04 soon

Comment: Here is what that yields...    /var/crash$ ls
_usr_bin_CubicSDR.1000.upload    _usr_bin_gr_filter_design.1000.upload
_usr_bin_CubicSDR.1000.uploaded  _usr_bin_gr_filter_design.1000.uploaded
_usr_bin_gqrx.1000.upload        _usr_libexec_tracker-extract.1000.upload
_usr_bin_gqrx.1000.uploaded      _usr_libexec_tracker-extract.1000.uploaded
/var/crash$      Not of much use; IMHO. I think "lshw" gives you a more relevant pic. of what when down during the upgrade !?